# Offline cache copies in Windows file sharing

Tags: proxy, samba, cache, cifs

I frequently access media files (music or video) on a remote Windows file share. My Internet connection is not very fast, and I find it a waste of bandwidth when I repeatedly access the same files. For example, I may listen to the same song 30 times in a month. So, I would like to cache files I've used.

I know Windows has an "Always available offline" feature but I dont' think it suit my needs.

1. I don't want to make the whole share "available offline" as the remote Windows file share is huge (in terabytes).
2. Making individual files "available offline" is tedious as the files are scattered in many different directories. It would be much more convenient if the system can simply cache those I've used.
3. I could also manually make a local copy each time I use a file... but this is even more troublesome than making each file "available offline"

Also

- New files are being added over time. but existing files on the share seldom change.
- Many of the files are rarely used. Some of the files are frequently used.
- I don't have a list of the most frequently used files.

It would be the best if I could tell Windows to cache the last accessed 10GB, but apparently it doesn't have this feature. So I think the best way is to have a SMB/CIFS caching proxy. What do you think?

PS1: I have a Linux box sitting around. Perhaps I should try to setup `samba4` as a caching proxy?

PS2: If there are better caching proxy software for NFS, WebDAV or any other file sharing protocols, please let me know. I can switch to use these protocols.